# How to directly identify the co ordinates of a city in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to achieve the following

home page: visitor will search for a city or location from the search field. The zoom level as per google documentation is below.

```
1: World
5: Landmass/continent
10: City
15: Streets
20: Buildings
```

On Search Page: I want to list all the properties which is there in the locality searched e.g. **California** so i want to show all the properties on map with the **Zoom level 10** .. but the issue is i am struggling to find the co ordinates of the city.. do i have to add all the cities co ordinates in the database? see below code.. how can i make `center: {lat: 19.1760, lng: 72.7954}` dynamic so it changes accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
    </style>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBkyMvhWRirAMPvBnjgzXEH6DIkjwXwW_A&callback=initMap">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: 19.1760, lng: 72.7954}
      });

      setMarkers(map);
    }

        var beaches = [
          ['Aksa Beach', 19.1760, 72.7954, 1],
          ['Juhu Beach', 19.0969, 72.8266, 1]
        ];

        function setMarkers(map) {

          var shape = {
            coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
            type: 'poly'
          };
          for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
            var beach = beaches[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
              map: map,
              shape: shape,
              title: beach[0],
              zIndex: beach[3]
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
            map.setZoom(20);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          });
          }

        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So in short how can i get the co ordinates of the city/continent/streen etc dynamically to render the map? as co ordinates are required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use geocoder.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': Address_text}, function(results, status) {
    if (status== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        loc_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc_lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng()]
        fmaddress = results[0].formatted_address;
        alert('LAT: '+loc_lat+', LON: '+loc_lon+' ADDRESS: '+fmaddress);
    } else {
        if(Address_text != '' && Address_text!= null) {
            alert('Couldnt get the X,Y');
        }
    }
});
```

Note, you wont be able to use location lat,lon, address, until the request is over, you have to wait for the request to get back, then use the data. Since JS works in asynchronous way. Dont forget to use '&libraries=places'. ->

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBkyMvhWRirAMPvBnjgzXEH6DIkjwXwW_A&libraries=places&callback=initMap
```